# How do I extract text that is not also part of a child node?

Tags: css, ruby, xpath, text, nokogiri

I'm using Ruby 2.4 and Nokogiri.  How do I extract text from a node that is not also part of another child element?  That is, if I had a node

```
<a>Text 1<b>Text 2</b></a>
```

I want to extract "Text 1" but not "Text 2".  If the node is

```
<c>Hello</c>
```

I can simply call

```
node.text
```

but "node.text" doesn't work for the more complex case I described above (It would return both "Text 1" and "Text 2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
doc.at('a').child.text
```

or

```
doc.at('a').children[0].text
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Nokogiri's `xpath` selector to get only the text of the parent element:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<a>Text 1<b>Text 2</b></a>")
doc.xpath("//a/text()").text
# => "Text 1"
```

Comment: THanks.  Is there any way to generalze this?  I gave the <a> element as an example, but the node will not always be named "a".

Comment: @Dave: What csexton wrote is easy enough to generalize to other elements.  Can you be more specific in stating your generalization concern?

Comment: If I have a varaible, "node", of type "Nokogiri::XML::Element", how do I extract the text that is not part of a child element?